# Utilizando conceito de pilha para inverter palavras

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Estou fazendo um trabalho de Algoritmos e Estrutura de Dados, que utiliza o conceito de pilha para fazer a inversão das palavras. Porém, quando estou compilando o programa, está apontando alguns erros que não sei como modificá-los.

Obs: Marquei os erros no programa em forma de comentários.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct cel {

char conteudo;
struct cel *prox;
} celula;

void empilha(char c, celula *topo) { /* Atenção Aqui*/

celula *nova;
nova = malloc( sizeof (celula)); /* Principal erro do programa!! */
nova->conteudo = c;
nova->prox = topo->prox;
topo->prox = nova;

}

char desempilha(celula *topo) {

char c;
celula *pt;
pt = topo->prox;
c = pt->conteudo;
topo->prox = pt->prox;
free(pt);
return c;

}

int main() {

char frase[50];
int i;
celula cabeca;
celula *topo;
topo = &cabeca; 
topo->prox = NULL;
printf("Informe a frase: ");
gets(frase); /* Possível erro aqui  ()*/
for (i=0; frase != '\0'; i++)
empilha(frase, topo); /* Talvez erro aqui ()*/
printf("\nInvertida: ");
while (topo->prox != NULL)
putchar(desempilha(topo));
putchar('\n');
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os erros que impedem o funcionamento do seu programa são esses:

- No lugar de `frase != '\0'` você deveria ter usado `frase[i] != '\0'`.
- No lugar de `empilha(frase, topo);`, você deveria usar `empilha(frase[i], topo);`

Entretanto, ainda faço outras observações importantes acerca do seu código:

- É bem mais fácil ler-se, entender-se e achar-se problemas em um código bem-identado.
- Nunca, jamais, em hipótese nenhuma, use a função [`gets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets). Essa função não deveria ter sido inventada nunca e é universalmente e unanimemente odiada por todos os programadores em C do mundo. É mais odiada do que `goto`. Sempre que você usa `gets`, um demônio vindo diretamente das profundezas do inferno é invocado ao plano dos mortais para trazer dor, maldição e tormento ao seu programa C. Mesmo se o mar ferver, se as estrelas caírem, se o Sol se apagar ou se o mundo acabar, ainda assim, não use a função `gets`. A função `gets` foi removida do padrão da linguagem C em 2011 para sempre e para nunca mais voltar. Já vai tarde. Utilize em seu lugar, `fgets`.

  Ao invés de `gets(frase);`, use `fgets(frase, 50, stdin);`.

Com essas mudanças, o seu programa fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct cel {
    char conteudo;
    struct cel *prox;
} celula;

void empilha(char c, celula *topo) {
    celula *nova = malloc(sizeof(celula));
    nova->conteudo = c;
    nova->prox = topo->prox;
    topo->prox = nova;
}

char desempilha(celula *topo) {
    celula *pt = topo->prox;
    char c = pt->conteudo;
    topo->prox = pt->prox;
    free(pt);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    char frase[50];
    celula cabeca;
    celula *topo = &cabeca;
    topo->prox = NULL;
    printf("Informe a frase: ");
    fgets(frase, 50, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        empilha(frase[i], topo);
    }
    printf("\nInvertida: ");
    while (topo->prox != NULL) {
        putchar(desempilha(topo));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/8shebA)

No entanto, o que você está usando não é exatamente uma pilha. A estrutura de dados que você criou tem uma cabeça que é um nó especial. Uma pilha implementada como uma lista simplesmente ligada, pelo conceito puro da definição da estrutura de dados não deveria ter nenhum nó com tratamento especial diferentes dos demais. Prova disso é que `topo->conteudo` não deve ser utilizado e o campo `conteudo` só faz sentido a partir do segundo nó. Isso pode ser resolvido ao dar uma estrutura diferente para a cabeça, ficando então assim o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct cel {
    char conteudo;
    struct cel *prox;
} celula;

typedef struct pilha {
    struct cel *cabeca;
} pilha;

void empilha(char c, pilha *p) {
    celula *nova = malloc(sizeof(celula));
    nova->conteudo = c;
    nova->prox = p->cabeca;
    p->cabeca = nova;
}

char desempilha(pilha *p) {
    celula *pt = p->cabeca;
    char c = pt->conteudo;
    p->cabeca = pt->prox;
    free(pt);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    char frase[50];
    pilha p;
    p.cabeca = NULL;
    printf("Informe a frase: ");
    fgets(frase, 50, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        empilha(frase[i], &p);
    }
    printf("\nInvertida: ");
    while (p.cabeca != NULL) {
        putchar(desempilha(&p));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/ysHTqV)

Por fim, note que o C++ é um pouco mais exigente que o C em relação a *casts*, de forma que isso:

```
celula *nova = malloc(sizeof(celula));
```

No C++ deveria ficar assim:

```
celula *nova = (celula *) malloc(sizeof(celula));
```

E considerando que você só quer inverter as palavras, mas não a ordem delas na frase, você precisará então de mais um laço. O seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct cel {
    char conteudo;
    struct cel *prox;
} celula;

typedef struct pilha {
    struct cel *cabeca;
} pilha;

void empilha(char c, pilha *p) {
    celula *nova = (celula *) malloc(sizeof(celula));
    nova->conteudo = c;
    nova->prox = p->cabeca;
    p->cabeca = nova;
}

char desempilha(pilha *p) {
    celula *pt = p->cabeca;
    char c = pt->conteudo;
    p->cabeca = pt->prox;
    free(pt);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    char frase[50];
    pilha p;
    p.cabeca = NULL;
    printf("Informe a frase: ");
    fgets(frase, 50, stdin);
    printf("\nInvertida: ");
    for (int i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (; frase[i] != '\0' && frase[i] != ' '; i++) {
            empilha(frase[i], &p);
        }
        while (p.cabeca != NULL) {
            putchar(desempilha(&p));
        }
        putchar(frase[i] == ' ' ? ' ' : '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/u8sbII)

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela aula dada, realmente ajudou muito no entendimento. Porém quando vou compilar o programa, mesmo assim apresenta erro. Segue o print: [link] (https://imgur.com/i9v8ngA)

Comment: "*Sempre que você usa gets, um demônio vindo diretamente das profundezas do inferno é invocado ao plano dos mortais para trazer dor, maldição e tormento ao seu programa C. Mesmo se o mar ferver, se as estrelas caírem, se o Sol se apagar ou se o mundo acabar, ainda assim, não use a função gets.*" eita trem **:)**

Comment: @KennedyMedeiros Ah, mas você está compilando ele como C++, e não como C. Esse é um ponto onde C e C++ são diferentes, pois o C++ exige o *cast*. Use `celula *nova = (celula *) malloc(sizeof(celula));`

Comment: @VictorStafusa muito obrigado, ajudou demais. Só estou com um probleminha agora haha, a frase deveria ficar assim: "ODAGIRBO UODUJA OTIUM" e não assim "OTIUM UODUJA ODAGIRBO". Vou tentar mudar isso aqui se der erro voltarei aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se puder me ajudar a corrigir esse erro mais rápido me ajudaria mais ainda. Pois sou leigo no assunto, estou tentando aprender algo por agora.

Comment: @KennedyMedeiros Deixa eu ver se entendi: Você quer inverter as letras da frase ou apenas inverter as letras das palavras, mas mantendo as palavras em ordem?

Comment: @VictorStafusa quero inverter a letra das palavras, porém quero manter as palavras em ordem sim.

Comment: @KennedyMedeiros Resposta editada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Perfeito. Muito Obrigado!