# Buscar o caractere mais frequente em um texto

Tags: c

Fiz assim, mas gostaria que o `printf` não ficasse se repetindo... Tem alguma forma de exibir somente o caractere mais frequente?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char string[100];
  char letras[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxzwyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZWY";
  int n1, n2, cont=0;

    printf ("\nEscreva um texto: \n");
    gets(string);

    for (n1=0; n1<strlen(letras); n1++)
    {
        for (n2=0; n2<strlen(string); n2++)
        {
            if (string[n2] == letras[n1])
            {
                cont++;
                printf ("\nA letra %c contem %d\n", string[n2], cont);
            }
        }

        cont=0;
    }

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você pode criar variáveis que armazenam a quantidade do caractere mais repetido e o próprio caractere; no laço, você verifica se `cont` é maior que a quantidade máxima atual e, se for, atualiza o valor e o caractere; no final do programa, basta exibí-los.

Comment: Monte um array de inteiros com uma posição para cada letra. Inicialize todas as posições com zero. Percorra a string com um `for` e em cada iteração, incremente a posição correspondente do array. No final, basta procurar a posição mais acessada do array. Cuidado com símbolos que não são letras tais como espaço em branco, vírgula e ponto final. E não use `gets(string)`, use `fgets(string, 100, stdin)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    char texto[82];
    char *p;
    int frequencia[256]; // São 256 caracteres ASCII.
    char caractere;
    int maiorFrequencia = 0x80000000; // Inicializado com o número mais negativo possível.

    // Informa da e aguarda a entrada do texto.
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Digite um texto:\n");
    fgets(texto, 80, stdin);

    // Inicializa frequencias.
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        frequencia[i] = 0;
    }

    // Popula frequencia com o texto digitado.
    p = texto;
    while (*p) {
        ++frequencia[*p++];
    }

    // Procura maior frequencia.
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) 
    {
        if (frequencia[i] > maiorFrequencia)
        {
            maiorFrequencia = frequencia[i];
            caractere = (char)i;
        }
    }

    // Imprime caractere de maior frequencia.
    switch (caractere)
    {
        case '\n':
            strcpy(texto, "Quebra de linha");
            break;
        case ' ':
            strcpy(texto, "Espaco");
            break;
        default:
            texto[0] = '"';
            texto[1] = caractere;
            texto[2] = '"';
            texto[3] = '\0';
            break;
    }
    printf("O caractere com maior frequencia e %s, com frequencia %d\n",
        texto, maiorFrequencia);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Nunca** use `gets`. Use `fgets`. Explico mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282265/132) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254693/132).
2. Sua abordagem está errada. Para achar a letra mais frequente, use uma tabela (com um array) para computar estas letras.
3. Lembre-se que `char` ocupa somente um byte de memória. Isso significa que a tabela tem 256 posições numeradas de 0 a 255.
4. A função `strlen` é lenta, pois ela percorre a string até o final dela para descobrir o tamanho. Ao usar ela como condição de parada do `for`, ela vai ser percorrida inteiramente em cada iteração. A solução é usar `strlen` apenas uma vez e guardar o resultado numa variável.

Logo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char string[100];
    char tabela[256];

    // Limpa a tabela.
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        tabela[i] = 0;
    }

    // Lê a frase do usuário.
    printf ("\nEscreva um texto: \n");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    int tamanho = strlen(string);

    // Monta a tabela de frequências.
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        tabela[string[i]]++;
    }

    // Busca o índice de maior ocorrência na tabela.
    int maior = 0;
    char letra = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        int t = tabela[i];
        if (t > maior) {
            maior = t;
            letra = (char) i;
        }
    }

    // Mostra o resultado.
    printf("\nO caractere '%c' aparece %d vezes.\n", letra, maior);

    // Fim.
    return 0;
}
```

Com essa entrada:

```
oRatoRoeuARoupaDoReiDeRomaEARainhaRoeuOResto.
```

Ele gera esse resultado:

```
O caractere 'R' aparece 8 vezes.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/H2tDuM)

Há um porém ainda. Se eu usar essa entrada:

```
O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma e a rainha roeu o resto.
```

O caractere que ocorre mais vezes é o espaço em branco. Isso provavelmente não é o que você quer. Também acontece que `r` (minúsculo) e `R` (maiúsculo) são caracteres diferentes. Para resolver isso, você pode mudar o `for` que monta a tabela para isso:

```
    // Monta a tabela de frequências.
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        char c = string[i];

        // Ignora o espaço.
        if (c == ' ') continue;

        // Se for uma letra minúscula, troca por maiúscula.
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') c = c - 'a' + 'A';

        // Contabiliza na tabela.
        tabela[c]++;
    }
```

Com essa entrada:

```
O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma e a rainha roeu o resto.
```

Ele gera esse resultado:

```
O caractere 'O' aparece 9 vezes.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/t17Mhp)