# Dúvida em programa recursivo para escrita de vogais em C

Tags: c

> Fazer uma função recursiva escrita na linguagem de programação C com dois parâmetros: uma string e a posição inicial que deve ser considerada na busca. A função deve escrever as vogais encontradas na string a partir da posição inicial em ordem contrária a ordem que aparecem na string, os demais caracteres não devem ser escritos. Não devem ser utilizados comandos de repetição. Exemplos de chamadas e caracteres escritos:
>
> - `escrevevogais("aeiou",0)` deve escrever ==> `uoiea`
> - `escrevevogais("aeiou",2)` deve escrever ==> `uoi`
> - `escrevevogais("programa",0)` deve escrever ==> `aao`
> - `escrevevogais("abcd",1)` não deve escrever nada

Como fazer?

Eis o código que tentei:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int escrevevogais(char s[50],int i){
    if(i==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        if((s[i]=='a')||(s[i]=='e')||(s[i]=='i')||(s[i]=='o')||(s[i]=='u')){
            printf("%s",s[i]);
        }
        int x=escrevevogais(s,i-1);
    }
}
int main(){
    char s[50];
    gets(s);
    int x=escrevevogais(s,strlen(s));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, o `int` de retorno da função `escrevevogais` não serve para nada. Assim sendo, convém mudar para `void`.

Segundo, não use `gets`. Falo mais sobre isso nessas outras respostas: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/310952/132), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254693/132) e [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282265/132).

Terceiro, a cada chamada recursiva, é necessário avançar-se uma letra na palavra. Dessa forma, quanto mais profunda a recursão, mais longe do início da string você está. Isso significa que a cada chamada recursiva, o `i` tem que ser **aumentado** em 1. No entanto, você estava diminuindo ao invés de aumentar. A palavra nunca muda, e portanto o primeiro parâmetro é sempre o mesmo.

Quarto, Você pode colocar a recursão antes ou depois de verificar se a letra é uma vogal:

- Se colocar a recursão depois da verificação da letra, ele vai visitar as letras uma a uma indo ao final da string, empilhando as chamadas recursivas e depois vai desempilhar todas as chamadas em ordem inversa, e como resultado, as letras vão aparecer na ordem.
- Se colocar a recursão antes da verificação da letra, ele vai empilhar as chamadas recursivas até o final e a medida que for desempilhando elas em ordem reversa, visitar as letras em ordem reversa também.

Portanto, você deve colocar a recursão antes da verificação da letra.

Quinto, a primeira posição da string é a zero. Isso significa que dar um `return` quando `i` for zero não é a abordagem correta.

Sexto, para escrever strings inteiras, use `"%s"` no `printf`. Para escrever caracteres isolados dentro de strings, use o `"%c"`. A variável `s` é uma sstring, portanto `s[i]` é um caaractere isolado e deve ser escrito com `"%c"`.

Vejo que o principal problema na sua tentativa é que você considerou que o `i` vai decrescendo de `strlen(s)` até chegar em zero, sendo que a abordagem evidenciada pelos exemplos dada é a oposta, o `i` vai crescendo até chegar no final da string (onde há o terminador nulo).

Considerando-se tudo isso, seu código deve ficar assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void escrevevogais(char s[50], int i) {
    if (s[i] == 0) return;
    escrevevogais(s, i + 1);
    if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u') {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char s[50];
    fgets(s, 50, stdin);
    escrevevogais(s, 0);
}
```

O programa não considera vogais maiúsculas, mas isso é fácil de se arrumar.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/M6yyt2)

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando a resposta do colega Victor Stafusa. Caso queira inserir palavras com letras maiusculas e minuscula bastar escrever a função da seguinte forma:

```
void escreverVogais(char s[],int i){

if(s[i] == 0){
    return;
}
else{
    escreverVogais(s,i + 1);
    if((s[i]=='a')||(s[i]=='e')||(s[i]=='i')||(s[i]=='o')||(s[i]=='u')){
        printf("%c",s[i]);
    }
    else if((s[i]=='A')||(s[i]=='E')||(s[i]=='I')||(s[i]=='O')||(s[i]=='U')){
        printf("%c",s[i]);
     } // if else interno
   } // if else externo

 }
```