# Como deletar um arquivo (nao txt) em C?

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou criando um programa que coloca as notas de cada aluno um arquivo diferente.
O usuario coloca o codigo do aluno e esse codigo vira o nome de um arquivo que não é txt (nao sei como faz ser txt).
Porem nao estou conseguindo excluir esse arquivo.
Por exemplo, o usuario vai entrar com o codigo do aluno e quero que o arquivo com esse codigo seja excluido.
Ja tentei usar a função remove(), mas só serve pra arquivo txt.
Tambem tentei usar a função unlink() mas nao entendi mt bem como ela funciona.

Desde ja, obg!!

```
void apagar()
{

    char nusp[8];

    printf("--------- CONSULTA ---------\n\n");

    printf("Digite o NUSP do aluno(a): ");

    gets(nusp);
    FILE *consultar;
    consultar = fopen(nusp,"r");
    if (consultar==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nAluno ainda nao cadastrado.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n");
        remove(nusp);
        printf("\nAluno removido com sucesso!\n\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode mostrar o código que já escreveu?

Comment: "*Ja tentei usar a função remove(), mas só serve pra arquivo txt.*" - Isso é no mínimo duvidoso. A função `remove()` não quer nem saber se o arquivo é ou não txt, ela remove qualquer arquivo. Provavelmente você fez alguma besteira no código tentando usá-la, então seria bom ver o seu código.

Comment: editei o post e coloquei o codigo

Comment: @VictorStafusa depende se for arquivo .dat ou .bin aí os comandos mudam

Comment: @YODA Olhe os dois exemplos [**aqui**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-delete-file/). No segundo exemplo, é um arquivo binário (o próprio programa).

Comment: @VictorStafusa entendi... obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode deletar um arquivo que está aberto. Feche o arquivo com `fclose(consultar);` antes de tentar deletá-lo.

E por favor, não use `gets` nunca. Os motivos para não usar `gets` eu explico [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254693/132) e também falo sobre isso [nesta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282265/132). Use `fgets(nusp, 8, stdin);` ao invés de `gets(nusp);`.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obg.
Acho tinha ouvido sobre n usar o gets, mas nao lembrava pq, agora só fgets, vlw hahaha